# Form processing in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have three questions about some code :

1. How does `isset($_POST['submit'])` knows when the submit button has been clicked. I dont get the the mechanics behind this ?
2. Why is each input element using a name with a value of `artist[]` with the square brackets like that ? Are we defining and array inside HTML ?
3. I was told that the value of name given to an input element has to match the name given to the `$_POST` variable. But in this case `$_POST` is using `artist` with without the square brackets. Whats going on here ?

.

```
 <html>

 <head></head>
 <body>

 <?php

 // check for submit
  if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   // and display form
   ?>

 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="artist[]" value="Bon Jovi">Bon Jovi
    <input type="checkbox" name="artist[]" value="N'Sync">N'Sync
    <input type="checkbox" name="artist" value="Boyzone">Boyzone
    <input type="checkbox" name="artist" value="Britney Spears">Britney Spears
    <input type="checkbox" name="artist" value="Jethro Tull">Jethro Tull
    <input type="checkbox" name="artist" value="Crosby, Stills & Nash">Crosby, Stills & Nash
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Select">
</form>

 <?php

 } else {

     // or display the selected artists
     // use a foreach loop to read and display array elements
     if (is_array($_POST['artist'])) {

         echo 'You selected: <br />';

         foreach ($_POST['artist'] as $a) {
             echo "<i>$a</i><br />";
         } 

     } else {

         echo 'Nothing selected';

     }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$_POST['submit']` is set when the form is submitted and a input field with name "submit" exists. In your case, the `<input type='submit'>` has a name of "submit". (You can also get the value of the submit button using $_POST['submit'] which holds the value).
2. The names have artist[] because it declares an array to be passed as the form is processed. You can use it to group values together. Usually, it's done by `artist[name]`, `artist[album]` etc. which can the be referenced in PHP using `_POST['artist']['name']`.
3. Sort of follows from 2. Using empty square brackets makes an array without associations. You'd reference the first field as `$_POST['artist'][0]` and next `$_POST['artist'][1]`.

When all fields have been given the same name, an array is built and you can reference it in PHP like 3.

Answer (score 4):

> 1.How does isset($_POST['submit']) know when the submit button has been clicked.

Clicking the submit button causes the browser to submit the form (and include the name/value of the clicked submit button in the data).

Submitting the form creates an HTTP request.

The PHP won't run except as a reaction to the server receiving an HTTP request.

The PHP examines the data to see if the submit buttons name/value in in it.

> 1. Why is each input element using a name with a value of "artist[]" with the square brackets like that?

Most form processing libraries will provide a way to access multiple elements with the same name as an array. PHP's requires that the name ends in `[]` before allowing that.

> I was told that the value of name given to an input element has to match the name given to the $_POST variable. But in this case $_POST is using "artist" with without the square brackets. Whats going on here?

PHP's form data parser treats `[]` as a message to create an array and not as part of the name. It is odd.

It does however, allow you to define such things as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[bar][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[bar][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[bar][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[oat][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[oat][]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[oat][]" value="3">
```

And then loop over `$_POST['foo']` to get an array of two items which can be looped over in turn.

Comment: the name attr "artist" without the brackets.. just seems incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

1. The submit button actually submits the form and it's a POST value on it's own. So if it's set it means that the form was submitted. Though, it would be better to check if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is equal to 'POST'.
2. Yes, it's defining an "array", but it's wrong because in the last 4 checkboxes it doesn't have the square brackets.
3. `$_POST['artist']` would contain an array with all the checkboxes values (true or false, depending on wheteher they were checked or not respectively).